# Pygame: Sprite won't draw

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

My issue is plain and simple: my sprite won't draw.
Because there's too much files to all post here, I'll link you to the github page for the project: 
https://github.com/kahrkunne/Julia-Longina-Balbina-Error 
The main file with the game loop is JLBE.py. The sprite is initialised at line 15 and then supposed to be drawn at line 45.

Comment: So when did you notice this error? You are quite far with the code have you not seen this error sooner?

Answer (score 0):

You never set the x and y position of the sprite rect.
You should use the passed variables to the Player class (`xcoord` and `ycoord`) to set the x and y variable of the `Player.rect` object.

```
...
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.x = xcoord
self.rect.y = ycoord
...
```

Comment: or shorter: `self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=xcoord, y=ycoord)`